# Hibernate does insert instead of update when i am using merge

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to make an update on database using Hibernate. When i call merge, it results a new row in database. I don't receive any error. The cod is working, but i want update not insert.

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Books")
public class Manual implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int idManual;
    private String denumire;
    private String disciplina;
    private Date dataPostare;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TipManual tipManual;


    private String emailContact;
    private String telefonContact;
    private double pret;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "username")
    private User userName;

    public Manual() {

    }

    public Manual(int idManual, String denumire, String disciplina, Date dataPostare, TipManual tipManual,
            String emailContact, String telefonContact, double pret, User userName) {
        super();
        this.idManual = idManual;
        this.denumire = denumire;
        this.disciplina = disciplina;
        this.dataPostare = dataPostare;
        this.tipManual = tipManual;
        this.emailContact = emailContact;
        this.telefonContact = telefonContact;
        this.pret = pret;
        this.userName=userName;
    }

    public int getIdManual() {
        return idManual;
    }

    public void setIdManual(int idManual) {
        this.idManual = idManual;
    }

    public String getDenumire() {
        return denumire;
    }

    public void setDenumire(String denumire) {
        this.denumire = denumire;
    }
```

This is my model class, i also tried to remove @GeneratedValue for my id, but the problem is the same.

My function for merge:

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public Manual updateBook(Manual book) {
        em.merge(book);
        em.flush();
        return book;
    }
```

Comment: Is there value in idManual of Manual entity when application calls updateBook ?

Comment: @adyjr, thx you are right

Comment: You are welcome @S.over17. If I Answer, do you mark my Answer as correct?

Comment: @adyjr, yes of course, just answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there value in **idManual** of **Manual** entity when application calls updateBook?

Check this, because if identifier isn't present, the entity will be inserted again.

Answer (score 0):

if your entity is detached entity that's will happend , more [info](http://java.boot.by/scbcd5-guide/ch06.html)